# Why does the shadow in my scene look like this?

Tags: shadows

I have been practicing Blender and I've been a fan of Dedouze so I'm trying to make an animation similar to his. However, after trying out his demo file and applying it to my scene, the shadows look different like they're not hitting a solid object and there are lines on the shadow. Can you guys help me on this?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear if this screenshot is yours or is it the sample? Anyhow there is nothing to compare so I can't tell what the problem is. Either add another screenshot of your work or if this is your work, then another of the work you are trying to follow. What is useful is attaching a blend file as well https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Try going into the properties for your light(s) and under _Shadow_ (expand the menu) enable "Contact Shadows".